# Duplicate chart data in developer survey

Tags: bug, survey, survey-2017

I noticed that the charts for 
[Years Since Learning to Code](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2017&utm_content=em-features&utm_source=so-owned#developer-profile-years-since-learning-to-code) and
[Years Coded Professionally in the Past](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2017&utm_content=em-features&utm_source=so-owned#developer-profile-years-coded-professionally-in-the-past) are exactly the same. This can't be correct.